# Are there any international water bodies codes (oceans, seas, etc.)?

Tags: standards, ocean

As you may know, there are 2 letter international continent codes:

- **`AF`** - Africa
- **`AN`** - Antarctica
- **`AS`** - Asia
- **`EU`** - Europe
- **`NA`** - North America
- **`OC`** - Oceania
- **`SA`** - South America

But what about water objects such as oceans, seas and so on? Are there any international codes for these types of objects (alphabetical, numeric)?

If no, are there any unique codes for them within a country?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: I think this is a question that would be better asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I also want to transfer the question and answer to Open Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links should answer your question:

http://www.marineregions.org/sources.php
and

http://www.iho.int/iho_pubs/standard/S-23/S-23_Ed3_1953_EN.pdf
and

https://www.yestravel.ru/world/appendix_e/

International Hydrographic organization, Names and Limits of Oceans and seas
http://www.iho.int/srv1/index.php?lang=en
Good luck and success...