# Clipping ocean water shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, ocean

My requirement is to find a reliable source of Ocean water shapefiles, this is because OSM or Geofabrik does not provide this information.

I eventually landed on this page:
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-ocean/

By clicking on "Download Ocean" I was able to obtain the shapefile for the global Ocean. I've analysed it on QGIS, however, it turns out that, it is one big polygon.

**My problems are:**

1) I want to be able to refer to this in parts instead of one big polygon, I want to be able to cut out an area of interest of the ocean.
I am using QGIS, I have tried several clipping tutorials, but I must be doing something wrong, I keep getting the "0 features" error.
Please recommend, if possible with steps how I may achieve this with this specific shapefile. (Area of interest anywhere in the globe you may choose)

2) Is there another source for better segmented out Ocean water shapefile?

3) Is this a good source for water shapefile data?, if not, what do you recommend?

Comment: You should limit your question to one question, so Q1 only above I feel.  For questions about source of data consider asking separate question(s) on Open Data SE

Comment: If you give a little more info about what problem you're trying to solve, you'll get better answers. E.g. why do you need the ocean boundaries (this will give us a sense of how resolved the shapefile needs to be and how many parts it should be composed of)? One thing you can do is to create a polygon layer, draw a polygon around your area of interest, then clip the Ocean polygon with the one you drew.

Comment: my need is in this example I need ocean shape file area around San Francisco.
Yes, like Ive said tried doing drawing the polygon and clipping in QGIS, however it was not successful, Im sure im doing something wrong :(

It would be great if you could show me step by step exactly how to do this with this very shapefile from that link

many thanks for the support

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310073/are-there-any-international-water-bodies-codes-oceans-seas-etc/310153#310153

Comment: The QGIS manual is all you need for this. I don't think you should expect someone to make you a customized guide considering the wealth of information already available for what you're trying to do. To help you when you encounter errors, we need to know exactly what you mean by "it was not successful."

Comment: You haven't given enough information for anyone to help you. Please explain the process you used to clip the polygon, and include screenshots of the settings in the tools you used. It's impossible to guess what went wrong without this information.

Comment: To answer your Q3, yes, natural earth is a good source for an ocean shapefile. It's exactly what I would have recommended. The problem is in your clipping process.

Comment: when you say "ocean shapefile area" do you mean the coastline?

Comment: Thanks,
This issue is resolved.
I was guided to use water shape file data from:
http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/water-polygons

Contd.....

Comment: My interest is to clip out water shape file around the SAn Francisco area,
I got help about this QGIS facility to clip by canvas extent, it turnd out as exactly needed. The other clipping method i tried to do and failed was to clip by using another custom drawn polygon area to clip out the required part from the water polygon shape file.
Like Ive said I did try many tutorials and online resources and only decided to create a post as an ulitmatum
Im also a noob in GIS, so sorry about the lack in detail.

Thanks everyone!